# Idiom to default a setting for most modes, except specific others?

Tags: init-file

I generally like `show-trailing-whitespace`. But it's distracting in shell/REPL modes, where for instance completion may leave a trailing space (e.g. `ls foo` <kbd>TAB</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> in `shell-mode`). Plus I'm not git- or diff-ing the contents.

What I came up with for my `init.el`:

```el
;; Show trailing whitespace in most modes...
(setq-default show-trailing-whitespace t)
;; ...except I don't like that in comint-modes (shells/REPLs), because
;; completion sometimes leaving a trailing space that's distracting to
;; have highlighted, and anyway I'm not git- or diff-ing the contents.
(add-hook 'comint-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))
```

As far as I can tell this is working fine. But I wonder if someone more-experienced might say, "The problem with doing it that way is X", or, "The idiomatic way to do that instead is Y"?

(I realize this might border on being an opinion or "best way" type of question. So I apologize in advance if it's not appropriate. But knowing the answer would help me, and maybe some other folks.)

Comment: Others can correct me if I'm wrong, but mode hooks are indeed the idiomatic way to make mode-specific adjustments.  The only tweak I might suggest is to wrap you customizations in a named function to add to the hook rather than use an anonymous lambda -- doing so will allow you easier inspection of your hooks, and also allow you to remove your customizations later if you so choose.

Comment: If `show-trailing-whitespace` is provided by a global minor mode, then the minor mode usually will provide user option to exclude some cases. And yes, you can wrap `show-trailing-whitespace` into a global minor mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on `show-trailing-whitespace` only when it makes sense, for example, in text and programming modes:

```
(defun my-show-trailing-whitespace ()
  (setq show-trailing-whitespace t))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'my-show-trailing-whitespace)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'my-show-trailing-whitespace)
```

or when you are editing files

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'my-show-trailing-whitespace)
```

Wrapping `show-trailing-whitespace` within a global minor mode works, but the code is complicated and it slows down Emacs. I suggest using `text-mode-hook/prog-mode-hook` or even more specific mode hook. And your own way looks good to me as well.

```
(define-minor-mode show-trailing-whitespace-mode
  "Toggle `show-trailing-whitespace'."
  nil nil nil
  (setq show-trailing-whitespace show-trailing-whitespace-mode))

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-show-trailing-whitespace-mode
  show-trailing-whitespace-mode
  show-trailing-whitespace-mode-on)

(defun show-trailing-whitespace-mode-on ()
  (cond ((eq (aref (buffer-name) 0) ?\s))
        (buffer-read-only)
        ((eq major-mode 'eshell-mode))
        ((eq major-mode 'tern-mode))
        ((derived-mode-p 'comint-mode))
        (t (show-trailing-whitespace-mode))))

(global-show-trailing-whitespace-mode)
```